# Error when using select_one() however working fine with find() method

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my code and when I convert it to select_one() method, it gives me error.

Code:

```
response = requests.get("https://near.org/blog/",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find("div", class_="bg-[#ffffff] grow rounded-br-[10px] rounded-bl-[10px] sm:rounded-bl-[0px] sm:rounded-tr-[10px] sm:rounded-br-[10px] py-[12px] px-[20px]").find("a").text.strip()
print(soup)
```

select_one() method code:

```
response = requests.get("https://near.org/blog/",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').select_one("div.bg-[#ffffff].grow.rounded-br-[10px].rounded-bl-[10px].sm:rounded-bl-[0px].sm:rounded-tr-[10px].sm:rounded-br-[10px].py-[12px].px-[20px] a").text.strip()
print(soup)
```

First code gives me correct output however second code gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way of using `select` in BeautifulSoup, using your example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get("https://near.org/blog/",headers=headers)
soup = bs(response.text, 'lxml').select_one('div[class="bg-[#ffffff] rounded-br-[10px] rounded-bl-[10px] sm:rounded-bl-[0px] sm:rounded-tr-[10px] md:rounded-[10px] py-[12px] px-[20px] w-[100%]"] a').text.strip()
print(soup)
```

Result in terminal:

```
NEAR’s Private Shard: Infrastructure for Enterprise, Built on the Open Web
```

You can find BeautifulSoup documentation [here](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Still getting the same error with your code. [image](https://i.imgur.com/Cvvx3Cu.jpg)

Comment: I test my responses, @AviThour. Try printing `response.text`, see what you get, maybe your IP was blacklisted. Also, do a `pip install -U bs4`, to make sure you're using up to date packages.

Comment: There is no issue per se with the example code, it works fine - Check what you get in response to your requests - On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I got <Response [200]> on the response. IP isn't blacklisted. Which bs4 are you using?

Comment: @AviThour: read my response above please: 'Try printing response.text'.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus yup, I am getting complete HTML output. No IP is blocked.

Comment: DId you update your bs4 library?